# Setting pin annotations on an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, maps

Hi I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but Im developing an iPhone app and i have an image of a location which I would like for the user to be able to pinch zoom and interact with as if it were a map. I would also want to be able to set pin's to certain location where the user can click the pin and see information about the location.
Pleas If the question lacks information, have the wrong tags or Is not relevant to this forum pleas comment before voting down!!
Thanks"

Comment: show us your code in the app

Comment: Hi I found the answer to this question to be to add an overlay to MKMapView. Here's a link to a  tutorial that helped me. http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your image and your pin in a `UIScrollView`.

Add main image:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    imgView.image = image;
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    imgView.frame = rect;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Then do the same for your pin but change its origin:

```
pinImageView.frame = CGRectMake(pinX, pinY, pinWidth, pinHeight);
```

You can find an example here:
[UIImageView pinch zooming in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746085/uiimageview-pinch-zooming-in-uiscrollview)

Comment: Hi I found the answer to this question to be to add an overlay to MKMapView. Here's a link to a  tutorial that helped me. http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial